# Rubymotion: How to add 2 subviews to a view with one addSubview call?

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

Here I create two views(bar and icon) and I would like to make one call to `@window.addSubview` to add them both.

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds
    @window.makeKeyAndVisible

    bar = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame [[0, 0], [320, 100]]

    icon= UIImageView.alloc.initWithFrame([[100,0], [100,100]])

    @window.addSubview bar   # I have two calls to addSubview
    @window.addSubview icon

  true
  end
end
```

I would like something like this:

```
@window.addSubview bar, icon
```

or

```
@window.addSubview [bar,icon]
```

I realize the difference is nominal but it seems like there should be a way to call `addSubview` on several views at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you are just begging to trip yourself and others up at a latter date by doing this, but if you must you can just reopen `UIView` and define the method yourself

```
class UIView
  def addSubviews *views
    views.flatten.each { |view| addSubview view }
  end
end
```

This should allow

```
@window.addSubviews [view_a, view_b]

# OR

@window.addSubviews view_a, view_b
```

To try it out here is a full example

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)

    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds
    @window.makeKeyAndVisible

    view_a = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame [[100, 100], [100, 100]]
    view_a.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor

    view_b = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame [[200, 200], [100, 100]]
    view_b.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor

    @window.addSubviews [view_a, view_b]

    true
  end
end

class UIView
  def addSubviews *views
    views.flatten.each { |view| addSubview view }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a single method to do what you want.  The normal ruby way would be this :

```
[bar,icon].each do |view|
  @window.addSubview view
end
```

or even shorter :

```
[bar, icon].each{|v| @window.addSubView(v) }
```

Comment: That works, but it is just as bulky as two separate calls. I was hoping for something a bit more elegant.

Comment: the addSubview method add a subview, not add an array of subviews. If you are not happy with that, you can implement addSubviews methods and use it instead.

Comment: @siuying is correct, the addSubView method is an Apple SDK method and has nothing to do with RubyMotion. If you want a method that takes an array instead, you'd need to implement it yourself.